# How to get requested permissions of an installed app knowing its package name?

Tags: java, android, permissions, package, installation

How can I find requested permissions of an installed app in Android knowing its package name?

I don't want a list of all installed apps and their requested permissions, as other questions ask, but only the requested permissions of one of them.

Ex. com.android.something -> [asked permissions]

Thank You!

F

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you it was EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PackageInfo` has [a `requestedPermissions` field](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) that tells you all of the permissions requested via `<uses-permission>`. You can get a `PackageInfo` from `PackageManager`.